# Using results of GROUP_CONCAT in another sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use the results contained in a GROUP_CONCAT in another query but i can't work out how to do this as they are in a comma separated list.

For example, if GROUP_CONCAT(sample) contained a,b,c,d,e,f I tried to do

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `this` IN GROUP_CONCAT(sample)
```

but i get a syntax error.

I can't use

```
 WHERE `this` = GROUP_CONCAT(sample)
```

because that tries to match `this` to the comma separated list

Is there a specific method to achieve this?

Comment: You do not need to use the results contained in a GROUP_CONCAT in another query. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`this`, GROUP_CONCAT(sample))
```

Or You can use (if there is no special reason to use `GROUP_CONCAT`)

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `this` IN (sample)
```

if `sample` is the column of `orders` table

Comment: sample is the results from another table.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Worked perfectly for me. Thanks for making me aware of `FIND_IN_SET`. This will be useful. :)

Comment: Then you should go for the first option `FIND_IN_SET`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just combine the two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM `orders`
WHERE exists (select 1
              from <other query without aggregation> s
              where this = s.sample
             )
```

This query can be optimized.  You can write:

```
select *
from orders o
where find_in_set(o.this, sample) > 0;
```

This has to use a full table scan and cannot take advantage of an index.